# How to send the results of a newman report to Datadog?

Tags: postman, datadog, postman-collection-runner, newman

I have built a small microservice that is connected to Datadog, i.e. API calls to this service using Postman are shown in Datadog. I have generated the newman report for the service using -

```
newman run collection.json --reporters cli,json --reporter-json-export output.json
```

Now, I want the contents of my newman report `output.json` to be shown in Datadog. Any help/idea on how to do that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please do following actions,

1. Please construct API call with your API key - that should post data to dataDog - [ref here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/using-the-api/)
2. Then write seperate nodejs script to call this api with attachment.
3. Call your script after newman execution